# "Мальчиш-Кибальчиш" современным взглядом

Tags: литература

В школе мы все изучали сказку Гайдара (правда, поколение, которое училось в 90-е, — уже нет). Но весьма любопытно было перечитать ее сейчас, будучи взрослой и пересмотрев многие взгляды.
А не кажется ли вам, что "Сказка о Мальчише-Кибальчише" изначально задумывалась автором как пародия, как сейчас говорят, стеб? Уж больно гротескно она звучит.

Comment: Cовременный  взгляд  на  патриотизм  и  предательство  какой-то  другой ?

Comment: К Егору Гайдару очень по разному относятся. Один так глядит, другой эдак.

Comment: Егор-то  здесь  совсем  ни  при  чём.

Comment: Так и Аркадий к современным реалиям никаким боком, правда?

Comment: Так  в  современных  реалиях  понятий  патриотизм  и  предательство  нет ?

Comment: Во времена Советской власти существовала единая точка зрения на эти вопросы, а сейчас у каждого свой взгляд. И в 1993 Е.Гайдар делал одно, а Руцкой совсем другое))) Кто из них был прав, я бы не рискнул ответить со всей категоричностью. История рассудит патриотов и предателей?

Answer (score 5):

" - И погиб Мальчиш-Кибальчиш... - произнесла Натка.
     При  этих  неожиданных словах  лицо  у  октябренка Карасикова сделалось
вдруг печальным,  растерянным,  и он уже не махал рукой. Синеглазая девчурка
нахмурилась,  а веснушчатое лицо Иоськи стало злым, как будто его только что
обманули или  обидели.  Ребята заворочались,  зашептались,  и  только Алька,
который знал уже эту сказку, один сидел спокойно".

Это отрывок из повести Гайдара "Военная тайна" (1935), в состав которой и входит сказка о Мальчише. Как-то на пародию никак не похоже. Смеётся человек над тем, во что не верит, а Гайдар в коммунизм и в подобных мальчишек верил, и более того сам в гражданскую войну своего рода кибальчишом и был.

Answer (score 2):

Задумывалась как пародия?! Уверена, что нет. Сказка абсолютно в духе своего времени.

А что до гротеска, так этот прием был тоже довольно характерен, многие его использовали. Время было такое, гротескное...